# Existence of continuous derivatives of partial functions and total differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, frechet-derivative

We know that for a function $\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ the existence and continuity of partial derivatives implies the differentiability of that function.

Will this hold true for functions on product spaces of arbitrary Banach spaces? I.e., given $f\colon E_1\times E_2\to F$ ($E_1,E_2,F$ being Banach spaces) and $(x,y)\in E_1\times E_2$, does the existence and continuity of $(x,y)\mapsto Df(\cdot,y)(x)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto Df(x,\cdot)(y)$ locally at $(x,y)$ imply $f$ to be differentiable at $(x,y)$?

I guess it won't because the proof in the euclidean case goes from $f(p)$ to $f(p+h)$ in finitely many steps along the coordinate axes... So, maybe it will hold in product spaces of Hilbert spaces? What would a counter-example be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still true, even in the Banach case. Because you have a finite number of factors, and the whole differentiable continuity on each of them.

To show this, apply the mean value equality two times to join $f (x,y)$ to $f (0,0)$ to see differentiability at 0 :

$$f (x,y) = f (0,0) + \int_0^1 {D_E f (tx, 0)(x)dt } + \int_0^1 {D_F f (x, ty)(y)dt } $$
$$= f (0,0) + \int_0^1 {D_E f (tx, 0)(x)dt } + \int_0^1 {D_F f (0, ty)(y)dt } + \int_0^1 {D_F f (x, ty)(y) -  D_F f (0, ty)(y) dt} $$

Where the last term is $o (|(x,y)|)$. EDIT : this is true because you should notice that continuity implies local uniform continuity.

You might want to know if a function $E \rightarrow F$ is continuously diffentiable on each finite subspace $G $, then it is differentiable ? 
EDIT : I am sorry, my counter example was not valid. Still, I think it should be false.

EDIT 2 : I have found one. Take $E = F = L^\infty$. Take the functions $(f_n)$ where $(f_n)$ is the sequence of functions from $\mathbf{R}$ to $[0,1]$ defined by $f_n(x) = cos(x)$ (I've just took a random smooth bounded function which is not $0$). Let $f$ the following function : it sends an element $(x_n)$ of $L^\infty$ to $(f_n(x_n))$ if $(x_n)$ is almost everywhere vanishing (let us note $F'$ the subspace of such sequences), $0$ on a supplementary $F''$ of $F'$, and extend $f$ by the relation $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ for $a \in F'$, $b \in F''$. Then $f$ not differentiable (not even continuous) ; furthermore, it is continuously differentiable on each finitely generated space of $L^\infty$. (I have still difficulties to find an example where $f$ is continuous, not differentiable, and continuously differentiable on each subspace of finite dimension ; it would be more interesting)

Nevertheless the result can still be generalized. Let $(E_i)$ subspaces of your Banach space $E$ which generates it in a Banach sense (i.e the closure of the space geneated by the $E_i$ is E). Let $D_i $ denote the partial differentials.

If you have existence of partial differentials of $f $ and :

- For all $x$, the majorations $|D_i f(x) | \leq M_{i,x}$ where $\sum_i M_{i,x}$ converges .
- uniform majorations $|D_if (x) - D_if (y)| \leq M_{i,U}$ over numerous open sets $U $ of $E$ whose union is $E$, where the sum of the $M_{i,U}$ over $i $ is convergent (kind of equicontinuity hypothesis)

You will have differentiability of f !

It is essentially the same proof of the case of two factors, in which case these hypothesis are trivially true.

Comment: Thanks, very nice, but it took me some time to write the first argument down explicitly. Two things:

I think we should establish a sufficient premise for your answer. With the notation from my question we actually need $(x,y)\mapsto \partial f(\cdot,y)(x)$ to be continuous on the whole space $E_1\times E_2$ and not just $x\mapsto \partial f(\cdot,0)(x)$ to be continuous in $0\in E_1$, as I assumed, right? (The same for the derivative of the second partial function). If yes, should the question or your answer be edited?

Comment: The other thing: I don't see why we need the remark on local uniform continuity? Doesn't the continuity in $0$ of $(x,y)\mapsto\Vert\partial_1f(tx,0) - \partial_1f(0,0)\Vert$ and analogous for the second partial derivative suffice for the argument to hold?

Comment: Ah ! You should edit your question, then ! :) Even in the finite dimensional case, the existence and continuity on the whole product (at least locally) of each partial derivative is needed. There is no more premise than in the finite dimension case.

Comment: Yes, for the exisrence of the two first terms, you just need the continuity you re evoking. The remark about "local uniform continuity"is for the majoration  of the last term. I mean $|D_Ff (a,b) - D_Ff (a',b')| \leq \epsilon$ where (a, b)  (a',b') are in a sufficently small open set U in the product containing (0,0). It is implied by the continuity on the whole product (locally near  (0,0)) of the partial derivative $D_Ff$.